What is the minimum Node version required to use with the Azure Feature Flag libs?
I’m working on a legacy app with a Node version around 14.2. It does not work with the Azure Feature Flag libs. What is the minimum Node version I need to get to to be able to use the libs?

I tried creating an application with Node 14.2, but it didn't work. I got the error below:


ERROR: npm v10.2.5 is known not to run on Node.js v14.21.3. This version of npm supports the following node versions: ^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0.

To avoid above error, I tried to downgrade the npm version to 8.11.0 but it's not possible.

So, try to upgrade the Node version to 18 or 20.
I tried in Node version 18.
Here I can successfully install @azure/app-configuration.

